# Are npm package checksums verified against their repos?

Tags: security, npm, version-control

`npm publish` and `git push origin` are two different commands to upload a package to both the npm registry and to your favourite repository host.

But is there no link between both of them? If someone with bad intentions were to publish a faulty package to npm, and a different non-faulty version to github/etc.. does npm do anything about it? Or will I need to verify package checksums myself?